# "Past" or "passed"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

There are a few questions about past vs. passed, but it seems to me that this is very much a subtle matter, where small changes can change the answer, so here is yet another one.

If you were to say, "Go past/passed the store, then take a left.", would it be *past* or *passed?*

A friend of mine insists that it is *passed,* but I disagree.  She is so convinced that it is *passed* that she believes I am being willfully ignorant.  I am not an expert in the English language, so it's possible that I'm wrong, but it would be a surprise to me if I were.  So, StackExchange, what's the verdict?  Who's right?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Past*, rather than *passed*, is certainly what is needed here, but it’s not, as others have said, an adverb when used in this way. It’s a preposition having *the store* as its complement.

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 9):

*[Past](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/past)* definition 13 (adverb): *So as to pass by or beyond.*

For *passed* to be the correct word, you would need to say something like this:

> I passed the store, then turned left.

But this:

> Go past the store, then turn left.

is undoubtedly correct.

Answer (score 5):

It's *past*; it's being used as a preposition in your example.  *Passed* is a verb (usually).

Here's an example using each one:

> - We went past the mall on the way to the store.
> - We passed the mall on the way to the store.
> - You should go ahead and pass the slow car.
> - You should go ahead and go past the slow car.