# Is the correct usage to say "speed passed" or "speed past"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I'm having a debate with a friend and to my surprise a Google search on this question didn't provide any answers.

In short which of the two sentences is correct?

> "I will speed passed the police officer"

or

> "I will speed past the police officer"

My own impression is that "passed" is correct because it means to move in front of someone. But the fact that it only sounds right in the past tense, even though we are talking future tense has me suspicious. I suppose the third option is "speed pass" but that just sounds awkward and wrong.

Any help is appreciated but please try to cite sources, we already have plenty of opinions and dictionary definitions, but no solid arguments or references to settle this debate.

The proposed duplicate does a good job, however it lacks a reference that would explain why one must use "past" when used as a preposition and "passed" when used as a verb. The inclusion of such a reference would satisfy this questiona s well.

Comment: Are our references allowed to *be* dictionary definitions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Past" or "passed"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51337/past-or-passed)

Comment: @KateBunting Isn't this the complementary question where past is acting as a preposition rather than an adverb? Although the final answer is the same.

Comment: @origimbo Sure as long as it makes a solid case.

Comment: I saw that answer, it didnt provide any references. So I have no way to verify or understand the answer.

Comment: The problem is the definition of both past and passed seem to fit.. so im not sure the dictionary alone explains which is correct. This is also why the duplicate answer proposed doesnt help me much, it doesnt appear to have any references to support which of the two would be correct.

Comment: Google is your friend: https://www.google.de/search?q=passed+or+past&rlz=1C9BKJA_enDE701DE701&oq=passed+or+past&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3j69i60.8388j0j8&hl=de&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: The original question would now be considered off-topic on ELU.

Comment: Seems to me the question should be about which word is correct in *writing*, because in spoken English, *past* and *passed* sound the same, at least to me and several dictionaries. I mean, the fact that they sound the same forms the basis for the whole question about the written forms.

Comment: @user9825893y50932 "you used the wrong word!"... "But the two words sound exactly the same!"... "Yea but I know which one you used, I know you."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take your sentence and rewrite it for the time before you reach the policeman. Hopefully you'll agree that the following works:

> I will speed toward the police officer

and that "toward" is playing the same role as you want "passed/past" to. Now look up [toward](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/towards?s=t) in your favourite dictionary, e.g. dictionary.com. In one of the early entries you will see something like

> **preposition**, Also, towards
>
> 1.
> in the direction of:
> to walk toward the river.

So, we want a preposition.

Now let's check [pass](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pass?s=t), [passed](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/passed?s=t) and [past](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/past?s=t) in our dictionary. We see for *pass*

> **verb (used with object)**
>
> **verb (used without object)**
>
> **noun**

for *passed*

> **adjective**

and finally for *past*

> **adjective**
>
> **noun**
>
> **adverb**
>
> **preposition**

So, the winner is the only preposition, i.e. *past*.

Comment: Thanks, I think that satisfies the need for a solid reference and explanation. Ill accept

Answer (score -1):

*I will speed past the cop.*
'will speed' - is the verb phrase.
'past' - is an adverb meaning - 'to pass from one side to another'

How will you speed? quickly? slowly? or past?

'to pass-passed' is a verb. You have finished the verb phrase with 'speed'. The next item is an adverb.
'past'(adverb, adjective, preposition) and 'passed'(**past** tense of to pass) are two words that are often mistaken. (Notice in **past tense**,  'past' is an adjective describing tense).
If you look in a dictionary you will find many examples.
I hope that clears up the argument.

Comment: _past the cop_ is a prepositional phrase.

Comment: Yes, you're right, at least it isn't a verb. ;-)